# How can I figure out the source of an error from code that occurs when I run it within a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook

I am running some code through a Jupyter notebook and I have been having an incredibly frustrating time trying to find the source of a bug that has been plaguing my work. I have set up my virtual environment (venv) in python to have these packages at this versions installed:

```
#For python 3.9.0
scipy==1.10.1
pandas==2.0.1
PyYAML==6.0
scikit-learn==1.2.2
statsmodels==0.14.0
natsort==8.3.1
plotly==5.14.1
seaborn==0.12.2
notebook==6.5.4
requests==2.31.0
openpyxl==3.1.2
kaleido==0.2.1
UpSetPlot==0.8.0
dash-bio==1.0.2
logomaker==0.8
pingouin==0.5.3
```

After the virtual environment is set up and the relevant packages are installed, I boot up Jupyte-notebook, import my code, and start using it to analyze some input data. Everything ostensibly works until I get to the statistical analysis part, where I get this error repeated multiple times:

```
/Users/bob/Documents/virtualEnv20230909/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:6832: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in _nct_sf
  return np.clip(_boost._nct_sf(x, df, nc), 0, 1)
/Users/bob/Documents/virtualEnv20230909/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:6826: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in _nct_cdf
  return np.clip(_boost._nct_cdf(x, df, nc), 0, 1)
/Users/bob/Documents/virtualEnv20230909/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:6832: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in _nct_sf
  return np.clip(_boost._nct_sf(x, df, nc), 0, 1)
```

Now, as far as I can tell, this error does not affect the results, but I'm not sure. What is more baffling is that my colleague, who ran the same code with her virtual environment set up with the same packages on her local machine, never experienced such an error.

Using the information of the traceback of the error, I decided to dig deeper myself into the problem which seemed to occur within the stats folder of scipy. I checked the file _continuous_distns.py, but the functions of _boost.nct_sf and _boost.nct_cdf are not defined there. So I looked within the _boost folder, but I cannot find this function's definition at all. It is referred to within the **init**.py, but otherwise, is not defined at all (you can check here https://github.com/pri-cph/scipy/tree/v1.10.1_dev/scipy/stats/_boost). Even more confusing, the error of `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in`  is not even mentioned in the same class as the two functions of _nct_sf or _nct_cdf. So it's the flow between these two functions and that error is not clear at all.

Debugging from the Jupyter notebook is primitive at best, since I need to restart the kernel anytime I modify the imported code. I tried to debug in VS Code, but even though I know approximately where the error occurs, I still can't pinpoint where the problem originates from, even with breakpoints.

Given that this error does not occur on my colleague's machine, I could reasonably assume
that the problem might be beyond the scope of the virtual environment we set up, but I have no way to ascertain that. Can anybody give me any tips for how I could more adequately debug the problem?

Comment: The error means that somewhere in the program there is probably a value created that is too long to store in a given datatype and it "overflows". You need to convert it to the correct datatype or/and reduce precision. But without more details, and MRE it's hard to tell what you can actually do about it. But rest assured that it has nothing to do with the environment if someone using the same environment is not getting the same error. It's about the values/data you put into the program.

Comment: @Geom I'm sorry I can't make a MRE at this time, hence why I am trying to get debugging tips rather than a solution at this time. But the problem is, my colleague is using the exact same input and code base as me, and she still is not getting that error. As far as I can tell, our output is the same, but additional work must be done to assure this. But any tips you can give would be most helpful.

Comment: Did you try running the same code in a Python script without Jupyter? Did you do that and see the issue? If so, then you can debug without the issues you say Jupyter is causing.

Comment: @Wayne I have not done that. Because I wanted to keep a consistent environment with my colleague, I have just been using Jupyter (which is a part of our standard set up). That said, if you think that debugging the code outside of Jupyter will help me pinpoint the problem more accurately, then I will do it. I will need to reconstruct some of the code to get it to work outside Jupyter, but it should not be that difficult. I will let you know how I proceed.

Comment: "Debugging from the Jupyter notebook is primitive at best,". I was just pointing out that given that statement you have alternatives you can use. "I wanted to keep a consistent environment with my colleague..." You can keep the same environment if you use the same environment. The Jupyter interface is separate from that if you stay in your virtual environment. You can even use IPython if you prefer to be closer to Jupyter.